# How can I merge cells with Apache POI without them forming a rectangular merged region?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

If a given Excel file contains cells like the following for example:

[image]

If trying to use **sheet.addMergedRegion** for the the cells that contain the value "foo" the outcome is

[image]

so the cells that contain the "bar" are actually added to the merged region.

How can this behavior be avoided so that the merged region ONLY contains the "foo" cells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a limitation of Apache POI. This is a limitation of Excel. This cannot be done in Excel, and Apache POI matches Excel. Therefore this cannot be done. What you are seeing is the expected behavior.

Comment: not limiting ourselfs to Apache POI, you mean this can not be done at all in Excel?

Comment: That is what I am saying. Unless you know something I do not about Excel, but if I open Excel and try this I cannot make it happen.

Excel will not allow you to merge cross sections like you described.

Comment: I wasn't implying that it could be done, hence the question. Nevertheless, thank you for the prompt answer.

Comment: Hey no problem. it was a serious comment about unless you knew something I didn't. You would be surprised how often I continue to learn things about Excel that I didn't know were possible. 

Good luck!